# WinDos.PAS not found

Tags: delphi

I'm looking for a file named WinDos.PAS which is not available in Delphi XE2. 
It should be an old library (I guess Delphi 1 or 2), but couldn't find anything yet...

Comment: Just remove the file from the list and see which identifiers are missing. Then you'll have to work out how to implement them somehow using modern features. The link Andreas points to seems promising but don't try to copy this code. You should consider how best to implement the missing functionality in new code.

Comment: Are you aware that you can edit questions and you can add comments. We keep asking you questions in comments but you never respond. If you were to engage more we could help you better? Why do you need to convert to 64 bit? Windows 64 runs 32 bit programs perfectly. Or is this really a Delphi 1 program?

Comment: Looking at the code Andreas links to it is clear this is 16 bit Windows 3.1 code. Delphi 1 era. I can't believe your original code is Delphi 2 which was 32 bit. This is why I think you are trying to update to modern Delphi. Because 64 bit OS can't run 16 bit code. You would find it easier to port to a 32 bit pre-Unicode Delphi first. Say Delphi 2007. You have rights to use that version when you buy XE2. I can't help feeling that we could help you better if you were more forthcoming.

Comment: A friend of mine want to run this program on a 64bit system which gives out a failure that it can't execute it.... I thought that it was a 32bit program, but I'm not shure. is there any possibility to find this out?

Comment: I believe it's a Delphi 1 16 bit program. How much source code is there. Should be easy enough to port to 32 bit program with Delphi 7 or Delphi 2007, but much harder to port to XE2 because you'd have to tackle Unicode string differences.

Comment: David Heffernan is misinforming you. WinDos is `Turbo Pascal for Windows` backward compatibility module for Windows 3.1 target. You have to rewrite any code depending on it.

Comment: @PrematureOptimization You sure? I saw lots of `int 21H` in there. Not really going to fly in 32 or 64 bit mode. This code requires DOS. So which of my comments is misinformation? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: In real mode, in windows 3.1 you could invoke INT 21h. Once you got out of real-mode, you couldn't.

Comment: @Warren No matter what, it ain't going to fly on 32 bit OS

Comment: My best guess is that this guy kept his code in 16 bit until he needed it on a 64 bit windows machine, which no longer has the NTVDM/win16 stuff.

Answer (score 4):

A Google search gave [this page](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/14496/19/ZipView.aspx) as one of the first hits.

Comment: ohh memories, I remember this unit (WinDos) from the Turbo Pascal era. those were good times. :)

Comment: This module will not help. Probably it even won't compile.

Comment: @Torbins: Well, but it is a perfect answer to the question. Indeed, the OP asked, "Where can I find WinDos.pas?"

Comment: Ah, the [WinDOS unit in Turbo Pascal](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22WinDOS+unit%22+%22Turbo+Pascal%22) memories of eons ago (Ralf Brown's Interrupt List)[http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm] and such... :)

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: What is the purpose of stackoverflow.com? Is it just a collection of google search results which just mislead people?

Answer (score 3):

The functions in WinDos.pas were intended to invoke software interrupts and do various "DOS" era operating system functions. You don't need it.

All the functions in WinDos.h should be replaced with modern calls to functions in the RTL, including functions to access date and time.   This unit was not dropped from XE2, or even XE, but has not been part of Delphi since version 2.0.

After removing the WinDos unit from the uses clause, as David said in a comment, you have two choices; Either implement your own helper functions, as a single line function:

```
function GetArgCount:Integer;
begin
   result := ParamCount; 
end;
```

Or, what would be even better, go find places where `GetArgCount` is called and change it to just call the modern function  `ParamCount`.  We call this "modernizing" your 16 bit era code. It's 2011. Time to update your code.

Answer (score 1):

> *A friend of mine want to run this program on a 64bit system which gives out a failure that it can't execute it.... I thought that it was a 32bit program, but I'm not shure. is there any possibility to find this out?*

If your program is compiled to use `WinDos.pas`, then it is a 16-bit program. Since 64-bit versions of Windows do not support 16-bit programs natively, you will have to find another way.

- You could port the program from 16-bit to 32-bit, but that could be a lot of work.
- Your friend could install the so-called ["Windows XP Mode"](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) which is Microsoft's supported method of running old 16-bit programs on a 64-bit operating system.